# How to read attributes of an object column, using Python Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe where the **'location'** column contains an object:

```
import pandas as pd

item1 = {
     'project': 'A',
     'location': {'country': 'united states', 'city': 'new york'},
     'raised_usd': 1.0}

item2 =  {
    'project': 'B',
    'location': {'country': 'united kingdom', 'city': 'cambridge'},
    'raised_usd': 5.0}

item3 =  {
    'project': 'C',
    'raised_usd': 10.0}

data = [item1, item2, item3]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(data))
df
```

[image]

I'd like to create an extra column, **'project_country'**, which contains just the country information, if available. I've tried the following:

```
def get_country(location):
    try:
        return location['country']
    except Exception:
        return 'n/a'

df['project_country'] = get_country(df['location'])
df
```

But this doesn't work:
[image]

How should I go about importing this field?

Comment: Strictly in Python those are **items** (of the dict), not attributes. Back in the original JSON they were attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) and pass your func to it:

```
In [62]:

def get_country(location):
    try:
        return location['country']
    except Exception:
        return 'n/a'
​
df['project_country'] = df['location'].apply(get_country)
df
Out[62]:
                                            location project  raised_usd  \
0   {'country': 'united states', 'city': 'new york'}       A           1   
1  {'country': 'united kingdom', 'city': 'cambrid...       B           5   
2                                                NaN       C          10   

  project_country  
0   united states  
1  united kingdom  
2             n/a
```

The reason your original code failed is because what is passed is the entire column or pandas Series:

```
In [64]:

def get_country(location):
    print(location)
    try:
        print(location['country'])
    except Exception:
        print('n/a')
​
get_country(df['location'])
0     {'country': 'united states', 'city': 'new york'}
1    {'country': 'united kingdom', 'city': 'cambrid...
2                                                  NaN
Name: location, dtype: object
n/a
```

As such an attempt to find the key using the entire Series raises a `KeyError` and you get `'n/a'` returned.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it - use `.str[<key>]`. It implicitly call `__getitem__` with `key` argument for each item:

```
In [17]: df['location'].str['country']
Out[17]: 
0     united states
1    united kingdom
2               NaN
Name: location, dtype: object
```

It returns `NaN` in case of error and returns value otherwise.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not seem to work anymore with the recent version of `pandas`. I'm getting "AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!`'.

Comment: @timgeb Which version do you use? I am testing with 1.2.1 right now and it works correctly.

Comment: Same as @VladyslavSuprunov I'm using 1.3.4 and it also works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way as EdChum pointed out is to use `apply` on the 'location' column. You could compress that code in one line:

```
In [15]: df['location'].apply(lambda v: v.get('country') if isinstance(v, dict) else '')
Out[15]: 
0     united states
1    united kingdom
2                  
Name: location, dtype: object
```

And, assign it to a column:

```
In [16]: df['country'] = df['location'].apply(lambda v: v.get('country') if isinstance(v, dict) else '')

In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
                                            location project  raised_usd  \
0  {u'country': u'united states', u'city': u'new ...       A           1   
1  {u'country': u'united kingdom', u'city': u'cam...       B           5   
2                                                NaN       C          10   

          country  
0   united states  
1  united kingdom  
2
```

Answer (score 0):

With `apply`, you can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html). Note we need to use `dropna()` since your column contains NaN:

```
from operator import itemgetter
df['location'].apply(itemgetter('country'))

df['location'].dropna().apply(itemgetter('country'))
0     united states
1    united kingdom
Name: location, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

When read csv file, you can use `converters` option:

```
def string_to_dict(dict_string):`
    try:
        return json.loads(dict_string)
    except Exception:
        return "N/A"

 df = pd.read_csv('../data/data.csv', converters={'locations': string_to_dict})
```

Access data by using `from pandas import json_normalize`:

```
normalized_locations = json_normalize(df['locations'])
df['country'] = normalized_locations['country']
```